# Differentiate answers and questions on the Votes tab of my profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

I often go back to the Votes tab under the Activity tab of my own profile so I can see if questions or answers I have voted on have been updated.

It would be nice when viewing the list if there was an indicator showing if my vote was on a question or on an answer. Right now it just shows the type of vote and the question title, even for answers.